# Smallest index of the largest element java?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

So I have written code to give me a the smallest index of the smallest element for an array meaning that if there are doubles in my array it would give me the one with the smallest index for example :

`myList = {1,3,1,4,5,5};`  when running the code it would give me the index of 0 and not 2

What I am having trouble doing is converting this code for a 2d array?

My code:

```
public static int indexSmall(int[] array)
{
    int index = 0;
    int low = array[index];
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        if (low > array[i])
        {
            low = array[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }

    return index;
}
```

Comment: I guess you just need a `break;` after `index = i;`

Comment: How do you want to apply this to a 2D array? What "trouble" are you having?

Comment: 2D array ? So would you say arr[1][5] is a smaller index or arr[5][1] ?

Comment: Yes how do you determine the smallest index of a 2D array?  Is 0,2 smaller than 2,0? What about 1,1?

Comment: We can say that, but it doesn't clear anything up. In the array `{{2,1},{1,2}}`, which is the "smallest" index?

Comment: @markspace I think OP wants smallest in terms of row major ordering

Comment: So what i mean is lets say I have this 2d array:    myList = {{2, 3, 7, 9} , {5, 8, 2, 4}}    what i what the code to do is print out the index 0,0 which refers to the first 2 of my 2d array

Comment: So instead of one `index`, you'll need to save two.  Should be a trivial fix.  If you're having trouble, please post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the same thing but you're going to have to utilize two variables in order to keep track of the row and column indices since it is no longer one index in a 2D array that you are looking for. What you want to return is simply up to you at this point.

```
public static int indexSmall(int[] array)
{
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    int low = array[row][col];
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) //array.length is the number of 
                                          //arrays in the 2D array aka the number of rows
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) //array[i].length is the number of elements
                                                 //in one of the arrays in the 2D arrays aka 
                                                 //the number of columns
            {
            if (low > array[i][j])
            {
                low = array[i][j];
                row = i;
                col = j
            }
        }
    }

    return row; //you can also return col or a combination of the two
}
```